# change the output value of an observable

Tags: angular

I want to retrieve a value from my API.
The currently returned value is an array of objects.

```
[
    {
        "products_id": 793781
    },
    {
        "products_id": 794543
    }
]
```

I would like to use this data to transform it into a number and thus display the number of products_id returned.

I think the method is going to be .length() but I don't know where to put it.

```
@Input() archiveVente: [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.ArchiveVente$ = this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Archive', 'Vente');
    console.log(this.ArchiveVente$);
}


getProducts(status, typeTransac):Observable<any> {
    //   console.log(this.baux);
    //   for(this.i=0; this.i<9;this.i++ ){
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append('status', status);
    params = params.append('typeTransac', typeTransac);

    return this.apiClient.get(this.ApiUrl, { params: params});                
}


<app-compteur [archiveVente]="ArchiveVente$ | async"></app-compteur>
```

Comment: Try this `this.ArchiveVente$ = this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Archive', 'Vente').count(product => product.products_id)` ?

https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/count.html

Comment: ERROR TypeError: this.dataMlsService.getProducts(...).count is not a function

Comment: i look your link

Comment: If you only have 1 emitted value (since it's HTTP it should be the case) use a map & get the length of your array.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a second observable from the first one (`archiveVente$`), and with `map` operator, get the length of array emitted inside.

```
  this.productsCount$ = this.ArchiveVente$.pipe(
    map(products => products?.length)
  );
```

But to make this working, you should correct your `getProducts` return type :

```
getProducts(status, typeTransac):Observable<Product[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('status', status);
  params = params.append('typeTransac', typeTransac);

  return this.apiClient.get<Product[]>(this.ApiUrl, { params: params});
}
```

And create the `Product` type.

Comment: why use htppParams to send an object?

Answer (score 0):

HttpParams is NOT for pass parameters. So simply

```
getProducts(status, typeTransac):Observable<any> {
          const data={status:status,typeTransac:typeTransac}
          return this.apiClient.get(this.ApiUrl,data).pipe(
               map((res:any[])=>{
              //here you has the response, the array, what do you want to do with this?
              //return an object with data and count?
              return {data:res,count:res.length}
              //return only the count?
              return res.length
          }));
           
        }
```

Comment: Hello @Eliseo, the .lenght method doesn't work. The 'length' property does not exist on the 'unknown'.ts(2339) type.

Comment: declare the type of the response as `((res:any[])=>{....}`, just corrected in code, thanks for the advertisment

Comment: Thanks for ur edit. Your solution seems to be error-free, but it still doesn't work.
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: SwitchMapOperator}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

When ever u think of a transform value to other **[map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map)** is the rxjs function.
it transform ur data from one shape to other shape.

so in simple words "u have an array and u want it length instead of that array"

```
this.productsCount$ = this.ArchiveVente$.pipe(
    map(array => array.length)
  );
```